# Match and replace only line breaks in string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace line break in string with blank.if string has only line break it should be replace with blank string if string has text along with line breaks it should not be replace with anything.

```
string test1 = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTestcompanyAC\r\nRegistration Number: 19871\r\n\r\n\r\nSTATEMENTS\r\n\r\nYear ended 31 December 2013\r\n\r\n"

string test2 = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

**output: test1 as it is and  test2=""**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string test2 = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";

if (test2.All(c => c == '\n' || c == '\r'))
    test2 = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `^` and `$` delimiters to match beginning and ending.

```
Regex.Replace(test2, @"^[\r\n]*$", String.Empty)
```

Comment: Regex is such overkill for such a simple thing.

Comment: Not sure how my solution doesn't fulfil the requirement "if only line breaks, replace with empty string. If anything else.. don't replace anything".

Comment: Oops sorry I've confused your post with Simon Svensson's

Answer (score 1):

Why would you bother with Regex.

This does what you need:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(string_variable_here))
    string_variable_here = "";
```

If you're just looking for a blank entry.. the above is all you need.

Comment: This will also empty strings like `string test3 = "        "`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, and a somewhat different attempt, but are you looking for a way to trim your string, to remove leading and ending whitespaces?

```
str = str.Trim();
```

That should give you

```
test1 = "TestcompanyAC\r\nRegistration Number: 19871\r\n\r\n\r\nSTATEMENTS\r\n\r\nYear ended 31 December 2013"
test2 = ""
```